# GCE hostname with hyphen in Ansible

Tags: google-compute-engine, ansible

I am going to make use of Ansible to provision my system in Google Compute Engine and the system has some manual created instances. One of the instances is named as testing-module.

Therefore I put this line in my playbook as a task

`something: {{ testing-module.private_ip }}`

Ansible results me as 

`fatal: [foo] => Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string. Make sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-'.`

The msg is telling me that the variable name in Ansible playbook cannot contain a hyphen. Question is the how can I reference to the private ip of testing-module?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit where this `testing-module` is defined? I don't mean the instance but the Ansible variable/object. I have only found two ways how to define a variable with a hyphen. One is the `set_fact` module, the other is `--extra-vars` passed on command line. You can't define vars with hyphens in any yaml file in Ansible, I believe since version 1.3 they check for it. In case this is the name of a host, you  can access it with `hostvars["testing-module"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `{{ foo.private_ip }}` then `foo` is the name of an Ansible variable, not the name of a host. When `foo` corresponds to the name of a host that Ansible has an inventory for then parameters like `"private_ip"` will be defined.

If you want to get the IP address of this host through Ansible, then you need to force Ansible to take inventory of that host, and to do that you need a task to run against it. Once you've done that you'll want to use the global variable `hostvars` to get at the actual information.  So you'll want something like this:

```
- hosts: testing-module
  tasks:
    - name: Gather Facts
      debug: msg="Getting facts for {{ inventory_hostname_short }}"

    - name: Test Facts
      debug msg="IP address is {{ hostvars['testing-module']['private_ip'] }}"

- hosts: primary-server
  tasks:
    - name: Test Facts of testing-module
      debug msg="IP address is {{ hostvars['testing-module']['private_ip'] }}"
```

Edit: Here is a link to the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) regarding the `hostvars` variable.  Also, a handy trick when you first start using variables like this is to simply display all the contents using the `debug` module:

```
- name: Display hostvars
  debug: var=hostvars
```

This will output a rather large JSON structure showing you all the information you can obtain through the `hostvars` variable.